# How to use "the" when there are many of them

Tags: articles, definite-article

Can I remove the word "the" before the word "analysis" in the below sentences?

1. On the basis of <del>**the**</del> analysis above, ...
2. Based on <del>**the**</del> analysis above, ...

And why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Provide more context or enlarge your question with clarity.

Comment: I updated the question and hope it is more clear now

Comment: No native English speaker would ever write "Based on the the analysis above" in English - why do you think you would? (Unless it was an analysis of the usage of the word "the", in which case quotation marks or italicization would help.)

Comment: @StuartF They would but they would complete the sentence, Based on the analysis above, we can conclude A, B and C.

Answer (score 1):

While *analysis* can be a mass-noun, in this context it is obviously referring to a particular piece or instance of analysis, and so is a singular count noun and should have an article.

Therefore *the analysis* is appropriate in these sentences.

*Based on analysis below* is grammatical, but would imply that what follwed was not a single piece of analysis ("the analysis") or multiple pieces of analysis ("the analyses"), but a generalized (and non-specific) lump of analysis which cannot be separated into individual analyses. It might be appropriate if for example the whole of the rest of the paper is given over to various bits of analysis. But it would be unusual.